# Batch not saving properly

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off 
title IPBlocker
:MAIN 
color A 
echo ====================================
echo Hello, his tool will help to block an IP from accessing you. 
set /p localip= What's your local IP [Default: 192.168.1.1]:
set /p user= Enter your router's username [root by default]:
set /p password= Enter your router's password:
set /p IP= Which IP do you want to block:
echo ==================================== 
echo printf \n%IP% >> /etc/config/blacklistips; /etc/init.d/firewall restart> blockedips.txt

echo The IP has been succesfully blocked and your router's firewall restarted.
pause
```

Hello, so I'm trying to create this batch, but when I run it I guess it breaks somewhere.

Is should save "printf \n%IP% >> /etc/config/blacklistips; /etc/init.d/firewall restart" in blockedips.txt, but instead it saves "printf \n ; /etc/init.d/firewall restart". So this ">> /etc/config/blacklistips" is not including in the file for some reason. And my question is why.

user, password and localip are used elsewhere later on connect with Putty (complete script or not, still doesn't save as it should). The main problem is that it doesn't save the necessary info in the text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape them by using the caret symbol like this:

```
^>^>
```

Reason is that it is a special character in batch so it has to be escaped.
Now the symbols are treated as literal characters.

Comment: You're a life saver.. Thank you very much, now it's working fine.

Comment: @user3586962 Note that you can accept an answer as solution for your problem, by clicking on the grey checkmark next to it. This does not only help to keep the system clean, but will also reward you for doing so :)