# batch script to make batch script

Tags: batch-file, text, copy, echo

ok simple i want to make a batch script that:

1. Makes export folder on users desktop
2. from new (as in not copying from somewhere) make a batch script in that folder that lists the contents of that folder after the user populates it and saves it to the desktop.

the problem i run in to is I'm trying to use echo to to copy the intended new script text from the original batch file into the new one like this:

```
@echo off 
mkdir "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Export"
echo dir "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Export" /W /A:-H /B > "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Readout.txt" > "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Export\Directoty_List.bat"
```

the problem is that the echo command sees the ">" as the end of the statement and writes the first part to a desktop text file, but i want it to see the 2nd ">" as that. how do i work around this?

Thank you

Comment: Escape it with a caret, ^>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch not saving properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41872223/batch-not-saving-properly)

Answer (score 0):

As @Richard said in the comments, you can escape the `>` with a carret sign `^>`. Most characters with special meaning in cmd can be escaped with the carret if you don't want to use that special meaning.
Normally the golden rule is: put everything between double quotes. Inside double quotes, the characters with special meanings are also escaped. Unfortunately the `echo` will print the quotation marks too so this won't really help in your case. It still is worth mentioning though, quotation marks help when setting values of variables with special characters, passing arguments with special characters, define paths with special characters (whitespaces or parenthesis for eg.), ... but not with `echo`.

There is one more advice I'd like to give: you can use `%userprofile%` instead of specifying the whole path `C:\Users\%username%`

```
@echo off
mkdir "%userprofile%\Desktop\Export"
echo dir "%userprofile%\Desktop\Export" /W /A:-H /B ^> "%userprofile%\Desktop\Readout.txt" > "%userprofile%\Desktop\Export\Directoty_List.bat"
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to place the string in parentheses.

@echo off

I don't think it is possible to out put to two files with your presented methodology:

```
mkdir "%userprofile%\Desktop\Export" 

(dir "%userprofile%\Desktop\Export" /W /A:-H /B) > %userprofile%\Desktop\Readout.txt

(echo %userprofile%\Desktop\Readout.txt) > "%userprofile%\Desktop\Export\Directoty_List.bat"
```

to make this statement one string you need to use the operators `()` and `&`.

```
mkdir "%userprofile%\Desktop\Export" & ((dir "%userprofile%\Desktop\Export" /W /A:-H /B) > %userprofile%\Desktop\Readout.txt) & (echo %userprofile%\Desktop\Readout.txt) > "%userprofile%\Desktop\Export\Directoty_List.bat"
```

Feel free to tinker with the operators!
rule of thumb, if your using `else`, `>` or `>>` you need brackets to avoid unnecessary `For` statements.

For Example:

```
for /f "skip=7 delims=:" %a in ('tree C:\Wallpapers /f') do echo %a >> C:\temp\1.txt
```

Will parse a directory tree skip the first 7 lines and append filenames to a txt file called "1".

The term `delims=:`is there to replace the default delimiter of `Space/Tab` with `:` as to read past any spaces in filenames. the `do` statement does not need to be there but I like to note it down until a finial draft is completed for the sake of organization. Windows will automatically interoperate the position of `do` as the function `do` and is a common function in batch script.

I use this sting as a backend to make HTML Gallery's.